# How do I show fewer projects in Package Explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse, package-explorer

I have a ton of projects in Eclipse Package Explorer and I want most of them to go away. How do I delete projects from the Package Explorer view (but keep the files)?

Comment: Select the project and delete. It ll ask u whether to delete the files permanently. Just dnt select the check box. The projects will vanish from the view. But they ll still be in the workspace for later imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just close the projects. Right-click on the top-level node of the project and select "Close Project". That's assuming you want to be able to use the project later. If you don't, you can delete the project - it will offer you the option of whether or not to delete the content files.

You might also consider using several different workspaces, each containing a few related projects.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit the DEL key on your keyboard while selecting the Project. It'll ask you if you want to keep the project-files

Comment: ENTF? After doing a search, that sounds like a German-specific key-name... unlikely to be useful to most readers of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on the project and click delete .But does not allow to delete it from the project location(Workspace)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it

Click on right corner of Project Explorer tab and open context menu. Select Filters option from menu.

[Here is the Screenshots process](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hide-closed-projects-eclipse-project-explorer-view/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use working sets. Each one will contain a set of projects, and you can change between them easily.

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple two-step process

- Close unwanted projects - right click and select "close project"
- Hide closed projects [(use this method)](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hide-closed-projects-eclipse-project-explorer-view/)